# Auto Rotates Movie View Screen in Swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, media-player

[image]

When I click Play button, mediaPlayer view show the following picture.
How to auto rotates when I play mediaPlayer? Please! help me.

Comment: Do you mean when you play the video, the video will rotates to full screen?

Comment: @aircraft Yes! the video will rotates to full screen.

Comment: if is the media-play is a html code?

Comment: No! I wrote with swift3 @aircraft

Comment: the video player is a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your `ViewController.m` file

```
  override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
  return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

And viewcontoller should be presented.

Comment: After I added your code, my project is work. After added  

UITapGestureRecognizer don't work.
  let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTapGesture))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

Comment: what are you try to do with `UITapGestureRecognizer ` ??

Comment: In my UITapGestureRecognizer  I added UIBackButton, PlayButton, Volume button for When I touch Screen these will appear.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxfyd0wfyk9f7gn/Screen%20Shot%202017-03-29%20at%204.13.58%20PM.png?dl=0

Before I added your code, my previous screen can be used UITapGestureRecognizer. I share my screen link.